# ID2D1RenderTarget::GetSize returing physical pixels instead of DIP

Tags: winapi, dpi, direct2d

I'm currently [getting started with Win32](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/learnwin32/learn-to-program-for-windows) and Direct2D and reached the [chapter on DPI and DIP](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/learnwin32/dpi-and-device-independent-pixels). At the very bottom it says `ID2D1RenderTarget::GetSize` returns size as DIP and `ID2D1RenderTarget::GetPixelSize` as physical pixels. Their individual documentation confirms that.
However I cannot observe that `ID2D1RenderTarget::GetSize` actually returns DIP.

I tested it by

1. setting the scale of one of my two otherwise identical displays to 175%,
2. adding `<dpiAwareness xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SMI/2016/WindowsSettings">PerMonitorV2</dpiAwareness>` to my application manifest,
3. obtaining

   ```
   D2D1_SIZE_U sizeP = pRenderTarget->GetPixelSize();
   D2D1_SIZE_F size = pRenderTarget->GetSize();
   ```

   in method `MainWindow::CalculateLayout` from [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/learnwin32/your-first-direct2d-program) example (and printing the values),
4. and moving the window from one screen to the other, and arbitrarily resizing it.

I can see the window-border changing size when moving from one display to another. However, the values in both `sizeP` and `size` (besides being int and float) are always identical and correspond to the *physical* size of the `ID2D1HwndRenderTarget`.

Since I do not expect the documentation to be flawed, I wonder what I am missing to actually get the DIP of the window of the `ID2D1HwndRenderTarget` `pRenderTarget`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The size is only relative to the DPI of the render target, set using `ID2D1RenderTarget::SetDpi`. This value is not automatically connected to the value provided by the display system, which can be queried using `ID2D1Factory::GetDesktopDpi` or `GetDpiForMonitor`.

Comment: Thanks. I am now reacting to `WM_DPICHANGED` with `FLOAT dpi = (FLOAT) GetDpiForWindow(m_hwnd); pRenderTarget->SetDpi(dpi, dpi);`. Apparently, `ID2D1Factory::GetDesktopDpi` is deprecated and instead `GetDpiForWindow` should be used in desktop apps.